# Possible null pointer exception on autocloseable idiom

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Consider the following try-with-resources block:

```
try (Foo foo = getAFoo()) {

}
```

For some class `Foo` that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

If `getAFoo()` were to return `null`, then would a null pointer exception be thrown on the closing brace (due to the runtime attempting to call `close`)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_null_try_with):

> After due consideration the JSR 334 expert group has decided the semantics of the try-with-resources statement on a null resource should be changed as follows: the compiler-generated calls to close a resource will only occur if the resource is non-null.

This means that you can close any `null` resource in a `try` (with resources) block without throwing an error (and the same when the program automatically tries to close the resource when the `try` ends).

Comment: Broken link but can be viewed through wayback machine in 2016 capture. For reference it was by Darcy-Oracle on Feb 16, 2011.
Also relevant bug report mentioned in blog: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7020047

Answer (score 0):

You implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, so the compiler wil try to close resource when done, but process to close a resource will only occur if the resource is `non-null`. So in this case I think no exception will be thrown.